# Basic Algorithm Analysis and While Loop Behaviour

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity, big-o

"Analyze the pseudocode below and give the asymptotic worst-case running time of each function as a Big-Theta expression."

I've included the code below, as well as commented each line's operation count. This question is using a hypothetical architecture where each primitive operation takes 1 unit of time.

```
1: procedure KSum1(n)
2:     S ← 0 // 1 for assignment
3:     k ← n // 1 for assignment
4:     while k ≥ 1 do // THIS IS THE PROBLEM
5:         for i = 1, 2, . . . , k do // n*(whatever the while loop is)
6:             S ← S + k // (1 for add + 1 for assignment)*(whatever the while loop is)
7:         end for
8:         k ← k/2  // (1 for divide + 1 for assignment)*(whatever the while loop is)
9:     end while
10:     return S // 1
11: end procedure
```

As you can see, I'm not sure how to handle the while loop in this case.

If n = 4, then it loops 4→2→1, so 3 plus an extra check for a total of 4.

If n = 7, then it loops 7→3.5→1.75, 3 plus 1 for a total of 4.

If n = 9, the loop is 9→4.5→2.25→1.125, 4 plus 1 for a total of 5.

Etc.

I'm having a hard time coming up with a pattern to express the while loop's repetitions as a function of n, and it's preventing me from finishing this problem. Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction? New to algorithm analysis and any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are you familiar with logarithms?

Comment: Technically, yes, but it's been several years since I've done any work with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The time complexity will be `O(log(n))`, which means that for a given `n` there will be `log(n)` steps needed to compute the algorithm (or more formally: the order of the function representing the given problem is `log(n)`).

You have done most of the job yourself in this analysis:

> If n = 4, then it loops 4→2→1, so 3 plus an extra check for a total of 4.
>
> If n = 7, then it loops 7→3.5→1.75, 3 plus 1 for a total of 4.
>
> If n = 9, the loop is 9→4.5→2.25→1.125, 4 plus 1 for a total of 5.

A "step" here is represented by a single right arrow, so for 4 and 7 there are 2 steps and for 9 there are 3 steps. Let's compare it with `floor(log(n))`:

```
`n = 4, log_2(4) = 2,             floor(log_2(4)) = 2, #arrows = 2`
`n = 7, log_2(7) = 2.80735492206, floor(log_2(7)) = 2, #arrows = 2`
`n = 9, log_2(9) = 3.16992500144, floor(log_2(9)) = 3, #arrows = 3`
```

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. The only problem I have with this is that my answer needs to be a Big-Theta expression, and this is Big-O. To my understanding, does that not mean every line must also be Big-Theta? It seems analogous to trying to get an exact sum with one of the summands being inexact.

Comment: In this case the algorithm will be both big-O and big-Omega, whichb means it will be bit-Theta (will have a tight bound).